# How to Rename Column name using DDL Statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to Rename **Column** name using **DDL** Statement in SQL

Comment: [SQL Server Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx) is a **great** and **FREELY** available resource that can answer this (and a great many more!) questions about SQL Server ... learn to use it !

Comment: I expected my Google search for renaming table columns with DDL to send me to Microsoft's documentation.  However, this page came up near the top of the search results and the documentation wasn't even on the first page.  So, this question and answer actually helped me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute this,

```
sp_RENAME 'TableName.[OldColumnName]' , '[NewColumnName]', 'COLUMN'
```

Comment: What if,wana use 'Alter Table' Sql Query Statement

Comment: @Aditya - you'll be disappointed?

Comment: @Aditya - Not currently supported. [Related connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/270126/extend-alter-table-to-allow-column-rename)